# How to run Go binaries in Google Colaboratory

Tags: go, kernel, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Now Google Colaboratory supports Python2 and Python3 kernels. Can I add a Go kernel so that I can use Go in Colab too?

I found a few examples [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/13), but it only has JavaScript and R, not for Go language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/vistec-AI/colab/blob/master/golang.ipynb), which you can remember easily with the shortcut `bit.ly/colabgo` or `colab.to/golang`.

Previous methods depend on having 2 notebooks, one for installation, the other for running. Now both tasks must be done in the same notebook above.

The notebook specify `gophernotes` as the kernel. At first it cannot be found, so Colab will default to `python3`. Just run the first cell, which will install gophernotes for you.

When the first cell finish, reload the browswer (Ctrl+R or use MENU). Colab will now find gophernotes. It can now run golang in any cell, except the first (which is python..ish).

Here's the code of the first cell, for reference. You cannot use this in a new Python notebook, because there is no way to change kernel to `gophernotes`. You can only do that by text editor, or copying another notebook.

```py
!apt install golang-go libzmq3-dev
%env GOPATH=/root/go
!go get -u github.com/gopherdata/gophernotes
!cp ~/go/bin/gophernotes /usr/bin/
!mkdir /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/gophernotes
!cp ~/go/src/github.com/gopherdata/gophernotes/kernel/* \
       /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/gophernotes
```

Comment: Should I run the first section on a new notebook on my drive?
Can you be more specific?

Comment: And if I'm sharing the notebook with others, do they need to run the first code section? or they can just run my notebook?

If they change/don't-change the code in the notebook?

Comment: You can run on any python notebook, new or old. If you share it, your friend need to run the first code as well, before runing your golang notebook.

Comment: for some odd reason i get error on the golang syntex (even tho I marked the golang as the kernel)

Comment: After run the above code. It still not work.
1. "Unrecognized runtime "gophernotes"; defaulting to "python3" Notebook settings"
2. "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'HTML'"

Comment: 10 minutes later, it works! Don't know why this delay.

Answer (score 1):

For others looking for the same question, for a more up-to-date answer: consider using [GoNB](https://github.com/janpfeifer/gonb) as a Jupyter kernel. It supports Google's Colab as well as Github Codespaces and Binder.